# Multiple Checkboxes to Show/Hide Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to find a way to have multiple check boxes that can show or hide a div.  Basically, I don't want a change function for each individual box.  I imagine there's a way to create a function that passes values etc. but I can't figure it out with check boxes.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/j2dm2597/)

```
<form>
    <label>Show Boxes</label>
    <br>
    <input class="one-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="one" checked>First
    <input class="two-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="two" checked>Second
    <input class="three-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="three" checked>Third
    <input class="four-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="four" checked>Fourth</form>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>

div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
.one {
    background: red;
}
.two {
    background: green;
}
.three {
    background: blue;
}
.four {
    background: black;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}

$('.one-box').change(function () {
    $('.one').toggleClass('hide');
});

$('.two-box').change(function () {
    $('.two').toggleClass('hide');
});

$('.three-box').change(function () {
    $('.three').toggleClass('hide');
});

$('.four-box').change(function () {
    $('.four').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: use CLASSES `.className` when ever you mean to target a whole group of objects.
To target individual objects, use IDs `#idName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compress this into one statement, by doing the following:

1) add a data attribute with the color on the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... data-target=".one">
```

2) Add a global handler like the following:

```
//Or, change all of the boxes to just .box, and use that below
$('.one-box,.two-box,.three-box,.four-box').change(function () {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: It would be even simpler with one class for all boxes. As there is not, one can also use `$("input[type=checkbox]")`.

Comment: The OP would have to change the function each time he added, removed or changed a div

Comment: Plus, there would be a redundancy, the checkboxes already have a name indicating their target

Comment: @BenPhilipp It's not always safe to assume there will be a coorelation between names for various reason.  It's not wrong to be explicit in situations.  I assume this is a mocked example, not necessarily showing the exact problem at hand.  This solution adds very little overhead; just add the target attribute - that's not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

check this jsfiddle. beware changes are also madee in html

http://jsfiddle.net/phqwbk4a/

```
<form>
<label>Show Boxes</label>
<br>
<input class="one-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="one" checked>First
<input class="two-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="two" checked>Second
<input class="three-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="three" checked>Third
<input class="four-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="four" checked>Fourth</form>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>


$('.cbox').change(function () {
var check = $(this);
box = check.data("box");    
if(check.is(':checked')){
    $("."+box).removeClass("hide");
}else{
    $("."+box).addClass("hide");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this:

```
function ToggleShow(checkbox, div) {
    $(checkbox).change(function () {
        $(div).toggleClass('hide');
    });
}
```

And then just call it and send the params like this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6dpm1dpb/) shows.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this: Check for the value that the input already has:
http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/rfhtw9jL/

```
$('.togglebox').change(function () {
    $("."+this.value).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Using classes to group the Checkboxes:

```
<form>
    <label>Show Boxes</label>
    <br>
    <input class="togglebox" id="one-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="one" checked>First
    <input class="togglebox" id="two-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="two" checked>Second
    <input class="togglebox" id="three-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="three" checked>Third
    <input class="togglebox" id="four-box" type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="four" checked>Fourth</form>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a class to each checkboxes as `chk`

```
$(".chk").on('change',function(){
var self=$(this);
    var aData= self.attr("value");
    $("."+aData).toggleClass('hide')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v0d93ec9/1/

Comment: why so complicated with the "self" variable and your aData in a separate step? I would suggest `$("."+this.value).toggleClass('hide');` (see my answer)

Comment: Its my habit to caching the variables, and Caching jQuery Selectors is  good  for Performance. I know here in this case its not necessary, but I used to do like this. BTW it's not at all complicated, instead it's much more readable from my point of view

Comment: I see your point
(by complicated I meant not as stream-lined)

Comment: I wish both of you could resolve issue if one checkbox in NOT checked. Try your jsfiddle and you will see that box is still there if it is unchecked. Make one box unchecked and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the toggle when you click on a checkbox. `$('input[type=checkbox]')` will follow all your checkboxes. If you have more than these checkboxes I suggest giving these all the same class and use `$('className')`. Since you already have the class name of your div in the value of your checkbox you can use `$(this).val()` to get it. Just replace your JS with this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    var div = '.' + $(this).val();
    $(div).toggleClass('hide');
});
```